# I am not getting it right MySQL tables that is created by combining the Keys of two other table how to join them

Tags: mysql, sql

**Assignment:**
List all staff who are in the Computing department by first name and last name
(using the format `first<space>last`, for example `John Doe`)

Schema:

- Departments(name)
- Owns(department, building)
- Buildings(number, name)
- Rooms(number, building, num_comp, capacity)

  - FK building REF Buildings(number)
- Units(code, name)
- Staff(id, firstname, lastname, address, dob, extension, mobile, email)
- worksIn(id, department)

  - FK id REF Staff(id)
  - FK end REF Departments(name)
- classes(id, unit, room, building, time, day )

  - FK id REF Staff(id) FK unit REF Units(code)
  - FK room, building REF Rooms(number, building)

**My Solution:**

```
Select Concat(firstName, space(3),LastName)
FROM staff,workIn
where staff.Id= workIn.Id
And   department="Computing"
```

I am not getting it to write which tables are required to show the required data.

Comment: If `worksIn.id` is the foreign key of `Staff(Id)` you query should work. Also `SELECT * FROM workIn WHERE department= 'Computing'` return any data?

Comment: Instead of giving all the table schema design, can you please add few sample data for `staff` and `workin` table and the expected output

Comment: If any of the columns in a concat function are null then the result will be null. If there is a doubt test for nulls. Also you should use explicit rather than implicit joins.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstName, space(3), LastName) 
FROM staff 
JOIN worksIn on worksIn.id = staff.id
JOIN Departments on Departments.id = worksIn.department 
WHERE Departments.name = 'Computing'
```

Comment: As per the original post, there is no `Id` in the `Departments` table.

Comment: If you want to update your question, [edit] it. (But you really should not pile on additional questions which are not part of your original problem. Wait for an answer and then ask a new question if you still can't figure it out.) Pinging people who edited your post should only be done if you have a question or comment about the actual edit.